# New to coding, trying to use string variable with readline to change value of another integer variable

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the input from `Console.ReadLine()` for `SpellDCAbilitymod` to change the value of the `int abilitymod` between one of the six integers following `abilitymod` so that the calculation at the bottom of the code automatically finds the users Spell Save DC depending on the user's input.

This is the relevant section of code I'm having trouble with:

```cs
int strmod = (strength - 10) / 2;//formula for Ability Modifiers
int dexmod = (dexterity - 10) / 2;
int conmod = (constitution - 10) / 2;
int intmod = (intelligence - 10) / 2;
int wismod = (wisdom - 10) / 2;
int chamod = (charisma - 10) / 2;
int abilitymod = 0;
int Strength = 1;
int Dexterity = 2;
int Constitution = 3;
int Intelligence = 4;
int Wisdom = 5;
int Charisma = 6;


Console.WriteLine("What is your spellcasting ability?");
string SpellDCAbilitymod = (Console.ReadLine());

if (SpellDCAbilitymod = Charisma)
{
    abilitymod = chamod;
}

Console.WriteLine("What is your level?");
int level = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int u = 0;
int v = 2;
int w = 3;
int x = 4;
int y = 5;
int z = 6;
if (level>0) //Changes value of proficiency based on level input
{
     u = v;
}
if (level>4)
{
     u = w;
}
if (level>8)
{
     u = x;
}
if (level>12)
{
     u = y;
}
if (level>16)
{
     u = z;
}
int proficiency = u;
Console.WriteLine("Strength:{0}(+{1})", strength, strmod);//Prints Ability Scores and Ability Score Modifiers
Console.WriteLine("Dexterity:{0}(+{1})", dexterity, dexmod);
Console.WriteLine("Constitution:{0}(+{1})", constitution, conmod);
Console.WriteLine("Intelligence:{0}(+{1})", intelligence, intmod);
Console.WriteLine("Wisdom:{0}(+{1})", wisdom, wismod);
Console.WriteLine("Charisma:{0}(+{1})", charisma, chamod);
Console.WriteLine("Proficiency:+{0}", proficiency);
int StuddedLeather = 12;
int AC = StuddedLeather + dexmod;
Console.WriteLine("AC:{0}", AC);
int SpellDC = 8 + proficiency + abilitymod; //Calculates Spell Save DC based on proficiency and abilitymod
Console.WriteLine("You Spellcasting Save DC is: {0}", SpellDC);
```

> Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: `if (SpellDCAbilitymod = Charisma)` one is a string and one is an int, you cant do that.  Next time please point out the line where the problem is happening

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes are here:

```
if (SpellDCAbilitymod = Charisma)
```

**A.** You should use `==` since you're comparing values, not assigning a value.

**B.** You're comparing a `string` (`SpellDCAbilitymod`) to an `int` (`Charisma`).

You should either convert `SpellDCAbilitymod` to an `int` or convert `Charisma` to a `string`.

Here's an example of a fix:

```
if (SpellDCAbilitymod == Charisma.ToString())
```

This will compare the `string` `SpellDCAbilitymod` to a `string` convertion of `Charisma`.

Note that it will not affect the `Charisma` variable. It will just use the convertion for the if statement.